# crash at exit when creating a QML application with Visual Studio and Qt 5.3

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I've been playing with QML application and extensions through qmlRegisterType, and I stumbled into a strange thing : I have 2 projects. The first one produces a dll with a custom QML type, and the second one is a really simple application which looks like this :

main.cpp :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import TestLib 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }

    HelloWorld {
        id: hello
        test: "Foo !!"
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: hello.test
        font.pointSize: 40
    }
}
```

When I run my project through Qt Creator, everything works fine, and when I click anywhere on the window, it closes properly.

But now, if I try to compile the exact same code through a Visual Studio project (I use and special version of Premake to generate the Visual Studio solution and project files which handle the Qt special files correctly) then everything compiles, runs fine, but as soon as I click on the window, I have a crash with the following callstack :

```
ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap() Unknown
kernel32.dll!HeapFree() Unknown
msvcr120.dll!free(void * pBlock) Line 51    C
TestLib.dll!000007fef7bb6d6c()  Unknown
Qt5Cored.dll!QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() Line 1936 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::~QObject() Line 1030  C++
Qt5Quickd.dll!QQuickItem::~QQuickItem() Line 2120   C++
Qt5Quickd.dll!QQuickRootItem::~QQuickRootItem() C++
Qt5Quickd.dll!QQuickRootItem::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)    C++
Qt5Quickd.dll!QQuickWindow::~QQuickWindow() Line 1102   C++
Qt5Quickd.dll!QQuickWindowQmlImpl::~QQuickWindowQmlImpl()   C++
Qt5Quickd.dll!QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement<QQuickWindowQmlImpl>::~QQmlElement<QQuickWindowQmlImpl>() Line 106   C++
Qt5Quickd.dll!QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement<QQuickWindowQmlImpl>::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int) C++
Qt5Qmld.dll!qDeleteAll<QList<QObject * __ptr64>::const_iterator>(QList<QObject *>::const_iterator begin, QList<QObject *>::const_iterator end) Line 323 C++
Qt5Qmld.dll!qDeleteAll<QList<QObject * __ptr64> >(const QList<QObject *> & c) Line 332  C++
Qt5Qmld.dll!QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::cleanUp() Line 64 C++
Qt5Qmld.dll!QQmlApplicationEngine::~QQmlApplicationEngine() Line 241    C++
TestApp.exe!000000013faf2630()  Unknown
TestApp.exe!000000013faf4197()  Unknown
```

I spent a lot of time browsing Google and such, but I couldn't find anything helpfull. I think that maybe I'm missing some compilation option in my projects, that Qt Creator automatically adds, but I don't know which one :/

I know that just looking at this question will probably not be sufficient to find a solution, so I prepared a small project that perfectly reproduces the problem. If you're willing to try it, feel free to drop me a message, and I'll send it to you (I don't have any dropbox account or equivalent, unfortunately)

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: I am concerned about msvcr120.dll. I would have expected msvcr120d.dll instead. The reason I mention this is it is not safe (without isolation because of more than 1 independent heap) to use Release dlls in a Debug application or Debug dlls in a release application.

Comment: And now I feel really stupid, I switched to the debug runtime and it now closes normally ... Thanks a lot, I could have spend a lot more time before noticing this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using at least part of Release CRT msvcr120.dll with your Debug application and debug Qt dlls. It is not safe to mix Debug and Release in the same application because this creates more than 1 independent heap. If you allocate memory in the release heap you can not free it in the Debug heap and vise-versa because doing so corrupts the heap. Also the heap corruption does not necessarily cause an instant crash at the next allocation / deallocation so it becomes hard to debug. As you found out using the correct CRT will fix this problem.